# WCF: The client and service bindings may be mismatched?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Trying to use Mtom message encoding with my WCF service to try & speed up the transfer of a large query result from SQL Server.

Here is my Server side WCF config:

```
 <service name="IsesService.IsesService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IsesService.IIsesService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" messageEncoding="Mtom" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And my Client side (WPF app) config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="ServiceReference.IIsesService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting *The client and service bindings may be mismatched.*...

Comment: Can you add messageEncoding="Mtom" in the client?

Comment: Nope it's a property of the binding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of your binding basicHttp should be the same on the service and on the client. You can paste everything between `<basicHttpBinding>` (including readerQuotas) from your service configuration to your client configuration to fix it.

Comment: Great that got things working. Unfortunately Motm didn't appear to cure the latency issues though...